# How to create person Account in Mule 4

Tags: salesforce, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to create a Person Account in Salesforce via Mule4 Salesforce connector but I can only see the Standard Account object and its field in the connector. I tried using standard Account but Person Account fields are not visible in it.
Do I need to enable something?

Comment: What is a Person Account and a Standard Account object? Seems that you are referring to custom information. You should provide those definitions.

Comment: They are Salesforce objects

Comment: Nevertheless it is information that should be added to the question to explain the problem. Where do you see Standard Account exactly? If in Studio, a screen shot could be useful too.

Comment: I guess you are talking about not seeing the metadata of the object. First, ensure you are using the last version of the Salesforce Connector. Then, you can try pushing the fields besides not seeing them to see what happens, but be careful with the RecordTypeID you are sending as explained here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46901/creating-a-person-account-in-salesforce-using-the-rest-api If the record gets created, you can report an issue about not showing all the available fields on the metadata.